# Dynamically reloading a row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am developing ERP project in java + spring 3.0 + Tiles

I am editing a record (i.e. Row) of the table dynamically.

After editing it I want to refresh that row (without refreshing the entire page) to show the edited result....

How to reload a row of a table dynamically then???

Below is my ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    url: EditTaskSubmiturl,
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        id:taskid,
        title:title,
        description:description,
        milestone:milestone,
        assignedTo:assignedTo,
        deadline:deadline,
        priority:priority
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Hellloo");
        alert(data);

        // for reloading the row I'm using the below line, but it's not working.
        imgval.parent('td').parent('tr').reload();
    }
});
```

Please help me.....

Comment: if you are using `php` use `ajax`!

Comment: You should post some code if you want us to help.

Comment: Sure I have posted my ajax function

Answer (score 1):

Give the table or row a unique id, such as `my-table`, then use jQuery's [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#my-table').load(window.location.href + ' #my-table');
```

**[edit]** Without know's what `data` is in your example, it's tough to say what to do. You can use jQuery's [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/). You can just target the content you want to change and use [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: But i think it will load my entire table.

Comment: Then just put it on a row. What's in `data`? HTML? Content to go in a row? You can use jQuery's `replaceWith`: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20replace%20with

Comment: I am using data table. So my table data are generated dynamically.

Comment: But there will be code in the DOM that you can still manipulate. You seem to have a reference to the row. Try `imgval.parent('td').parent('tr').replaceWith(data);`. But I have no idea if that will work because *you haven't told me what `data` is!*

Comment: To remove a row from the page i am using the code " imgval.parent('td').parent('tr').remove();" so now if I edit a row then edited content should be shown as my data table row content.

Comment: "data" of the ajax function contains string "Successfully updated".

Comment: And where do you want that string? If a table row? I think you actually want it in a table cell. What exactly is `imgval`? However you get the `td` you want to replace, just assign it to something like `$td` and use `$td.text(data);`